# Discord.js - Is there a way to setup a click event handler?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, discord.js

I have a bot that lists out a bunch of audio clips with the command `!audio`

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    const audioFolder = './audio/';
    const fs = require('fs');
    fs.readdir(audioFolder, (err, files) => {
        let filelist = '';
        files.length && files.forEach(file => {
            const audioFile = file.replace('.mp3', '');
            filelist += `${audioFile}\n`;
        });
        message.channel.send(`${filelist}`);
    });
}
```

The other command is `!play filename`

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    const   audioFolder = './audio/';
    const   fs = require('fs');
    const   fileName = args.join(' ');

    if( !fileName )  {
        message.channel.send(`Please request a filename. Example: !play filename`);
        return;
    }

    fs.readdir(audioFolder, (err, files) => {
        if( !files.includes(`${fileName}.mp3`) ) {
            message.channel.send(`File '${fileName}' does not exist, use !audio to see the full list of audio files.`);
            return;
        }

        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

        if( !voiceChannel ) {
            message.channel.send(`You must be in a voice channel to use this command.`);
            return;
        }
    
        voiceChannel.join()
            .then(connection => {
                const dispatcher = connection.play(`./audio/${fileName}.mp3`);
                dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
                    voiceChannel.leave();
                });
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    });
}
```

What I want is to eliminate having to use the `!play` command. When the list of audio files comes out when using `!audio` I would like a way for users to click on the individual file and it runs a similar function to the play command based on the clicked file.

I cant find anything about click events within discordjs.

Any ideas here?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible (if I understand your question correctly)

Comment: The way I see it, a possible creative solution is to use reactions. Other than that, you'll probably have to use a web server and links.